# Convert HTML string to Jquery selector

Tags: jquery, microsoft-metro

I have HTML text like this which is retrieved using WinJS.xhr (Metro).

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="getMe">
Something
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to convert it to a JQuery object for using the selectors on it. For example:

```
$("#getMe").text("Something different");
```

@Mark:
I tried to use this but I can't get the text.

```
var yourString = "<html><body><div id=\"getMe\">TEST</div></body></html>"// somehow set to the above string
$el = $(yourString).find("#getMe"); 
console.log($el.text());
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. $("#getMe") returns a jQuery object already. Is that not what you are trying to do? You can assign this to a local variable. var $el = $("#getMe")

Comment: I mean I have HTML string variable. How to get #getMe from that string or even change that #getMe's text.

Comment: What is your HTML string variable?

Comment: >>> var myString = "< html > ... < /html >";

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for based on your last comment.

```
var myString = "<html>...</html>",
    $el = $(myString).find("#getMe"); // $el = the element you wanted.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SCY9b/1/

Comment: I think its because you are including the html and body tags in your html string. I tested with and without it and without worked. If that is the case you can use string manipulation to strip out the <html><body> tags from your string.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your html string is in a variable then you can do this:

```
 var yourString = // somehow set to the above string

 var $html = $(yourString);
 $html.find("#getMe").text("Something different");

 // and then to actually show it on the page:
 $html.appendTo("body");
 // or to just add that "getMe" div to the page:
 $html.find("#getMe").appendTo("body");
```